# Javascript window not showing proper dimensions and not resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

`var customWindow = window.open("http://www.wrox.com/", "height=200,width=100,top=900,left=970,resizable=yes");`

No matter how many window dimensions I change in my code, when I run the code, the window opens with the same dimensions. Further more, window opens at different location with different dimensions with chrome vs default system web browser in eclipse.

1. Why, altering dimensions do not change the window size?
2. Why, window location and dimensions vary in eclipse browser vs chrome ?
3. Although resize flag is set to true, the 'resize' event has no effect. Why is it so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    var customWindow = window.open("http://www.wrox.com/", "height=200,width=100,top=900,left=970,resizable=yes");
//  customWindow.document.write("my window"); 

    function customMoveBy() {
        //move the window right by 250 pixels and down by 250 pixels 
        customWindow.moveBy(250, 250);
        customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customResizeTo() {
        //resize the window to have a width of 150 and a height of 300 
        customWindow.resizeTo(150, 300);
        customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customResizeBy() {
        //resize the window to be 150 pixels wider, but leave the height alone 
        customWindow.resizeBy(150, 0);
        customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customMoveTo() {
        //move back to the upper-left corner of the screen (0,0) 
        customWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
        customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customClose() {
        customWindow.close();
    }

</script>


</head>
<body>
<input type = "submit" value = "moveBy" onclick = "customMoveBy()"> </input>
<input type = "submit" value = "resizeTo" onclick = "customResizeTo()"> </input>
<input type = "submit" value = "resizeBy" onclick = "customResizeBy()"> </input> 
<input type = "submit" value = "moveTo" onclick = "customMoveTo()"> </input>
<input type = "submit" value = "customClose" onclick = "customClose()"> </input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the second parameter of [`window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features) is the windowName. the window features string should be third

Answer (score 3):

you are not calling the open function correctly,it's

```
window.open(URL,name,features,replace)
```

, you put the features string at the "name" parameter's place

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var customWindow;
     //  customWindow.document.write("my window"); 

    function customMoveBy() {
      //move the window right by 250 pixels and down by 250 pixels 
      customWindow.moveBy(250, 250);
      customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customResizeTo() {
      //resize the window to have a width of 150 and a height of 300 
      customWindow.resizeTo(150, 300);
      customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customResizeBy() {
      //resize the window to be 150 pixels wider, but leave the height alone 
      customWindow.resizeBy(150, 0);
      customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customMoveTo() {
      //move back to the upper-left corner of the screen (0,0) 
      customWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
      customWindow.focus();
    }

    function customClose() {
      customWindow.close();
    }

    function open() {
      customWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="moveBy" onclick="customMoveBy()"></input>
<input type="submit" value="resizeTo" onclick="customResizeTo()"></input>
<input type="submit" value="resizeBy" onclick="customResizeBy()"></input>
<input type="submit" value="moveTo" onclick="customMoveTo()"></input>
<input type="submit" value="customClose" onclick="customClose()"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Open" onclick="Open()"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is name. Specs is third parameter. This should be

> var customWindow = window.open("http://www.wrox.com/", "name", "height=200,width=100,top=900,left=970,resizable=yes");

But the main  problem of html, not everything works everywhere is still there